# Angular - General Purpose Directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a generic `directive` which I'd like to use in any Angular page in our site. I don't want to force each page to use the same `app` variable. How would I change this directive to be generic so that it could be just added as a dependency (included as a separate js file of course)?

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
 return {
  restrict: 'AE',
  replace: 'true',
  scope: {
  name: '@',
 },
 template: '<h3 >Hello {{name}}</h3> ',

   }
  };
});
```

Comment: while the answer provided here makes sense and is what I would recommend using, I feel like the question is a bit confusing anyway.  what does "I don't want to force each page to use the same app variable` mean, exactly?  are you saying that you have multiple different apps running?  because the general paradigm is that each "page" in an angular app is just a partial view, and the controller is what changes, not the app....

Comment: A better way to word it would be, how to create a common resource that I could share with any Angular devloper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `common` module, declare your directive on it and use it as a module dependency on each of your apps. By adding the module on your app module dependencies you'll be able to use your directive and also every provider your've declared on your `common` module.

`/common.module.js`

```
;(function() {

    var commom = angular.module('common', []);

    commom.directive('helloWorld', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                name: '@',
            },
            template: '<h3 >Hello {{name}}</h3> ',
        };
    });

})();
```

`/index.html`

```
<html>
...
<body ng-app="myapp">

    <hello-world name="World"></hello-world>

    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="common.js"></script>
    <script>    
        var app = angular.module('myapp', ['common']);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: AH, so the trick is to create a new general module off the static angular